# Python if else statement not working in reduce lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I'm new to `lambda` and `reduce` in Python and I don't understand why this function doesn't work:

```
def my_func(str):
    symbols = ['_', '-']
    return reduce(lambda x, y: ' ' + y if x in symbols else x + y, str)

my_func('foo_bar-baz')  # 'foo_bar-baz'
```

I expected the output to be `'foo bar baz'`.

Does anyone understand what's wrong here?

Comment: Remember that `str` is a built-in so you probably shouldn't name your variables/parameters that

Comment: `if x in symbols` - *`x`*? Why `x`?

Comment: Why do you expect `foo bar baz`? What do you expect the result of applying your lambda to inputs `'foo'` and `'_'` to be? What is the actual result of applying your lambda to inputs `'foo'` and `'_'`?

Comment: Why not use `replace` or `re.sub`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the order of the arguments to `reduce`'s function argument. The first argument is the running total, the second is the new data. In your example, `x` is the built-up string, `y` is the new character.

Try this:

```
def my_func(str):
    symbols = ['_', '-']
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + (' ' if y in symbols else y), str)

print my_func('foo_bar-baz')  # 'foo bar baz'
```

Note the bug in this: in the first call to the lambda expression, `x` is `str[0]`, and `y` is `str[1]`. Thus, if the first character in the passed-in string is a symbol, it is not translated.

```
print my_func('-foo_bar-baz')
-foo bar baz
```

This can be solved by providing the third argument to `reduce()`:

```
def my_func(str):
    symbols = ['_', '-']
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + (' ' if y in symbols else y), str, '')

print my_func('foo_bar-baz')  # 'foo bar baz'
print my_func('-foo_bar-baz')  # ' foo bar baz'
```

Comment: You may want to use `''` as the initiator (3rd argument), to handle `_` or `-` at the start of the string.

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: You are right. I expected x to be the the current position of the string and y to be the next. Now I get it. I think in JS it was a little different.